# Django ready in AppConfig is stuck when starting a thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-apps

I'm trying to create a background thread in my Django project. In order to do that I created a new app under my project and defined an `AppConfig` as follows:

```
class WebhooksConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "my_app"

    def ready(self):
        super(WebhooksConfig, self).ready()
        MyListener.start()
```

The `MyListener.start()` method looks as follows:

```
@classmethod
def start(cls):
    worker = Thread(target=cls.my_entry_point)
    worker.start()
```

I would expect that after `worker.start()` the main thread will be freed and the `ready` method will be finished. Instead, it looks like this tread start is hanging the entire app.
If I add `daemon=True` to the `Thread` initialization, it works. But I don't want my thread to be daemonized.

Comment: What do you need your thread for ?

Have you consider using [django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq) ?

Comment: @exho - I want to have some polling mechaism that runs in the background

Comment: Trying to use threads in django is asking for troubles, and python threads are of very limited use anyway because of the gil. Use an async task queue instead (celery, django-rq, huey etc)